# Turn wordpress filtration into function

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have a list of wordpress pages filtered by custom taxonomy. How can I turn this into wp function to use with shortcode?
Here is working filtration:

```
<?
$custom_terms = get_terms('csgroup');

foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array('post_type' => 'page', 'csgroup' => 'digital-expert-group',
    // $args = array('post_type' => 'page', 'csgroup' => 'management-consultants-group',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'csgroup',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
            ),
        ),
     );

     $loop = new WP_Query($args);
     if($loop->have_posts()) {
        echo '<h2>'.$custom_term->name.'</h2>';

        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br>';
        endwhile;
     }
}

wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

I want to get this:

```
function l1category_list_func(){

==my php code with list of pages==

}

add_shortcode( 'l1category_list', 'l1category_list_func' );
```

Comment: You mean like what is described here?:  https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/wordpress-shortcodes-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use the return statement to return a concatenated string of the outputs that you were echoing before.

```
function l1category_list_func(){
    $output = '';
    $custom_terms = get_terms('csgroup');

    foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
        wp_reset_query();
        $args = array('post_type' => 'page', 'csgroup' => 'digital-expert-group',
        // $args = array('post_type' => 'page', 'csgroup' => 'management-consultants-group',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'csgroup',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
                ),
            ),
         );

         $loop = new WP_Query($args);
         if($loop->have_posts()) {
            echo '<h2>'.$custom_term->name.'</h2>';

            while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
                $output .= '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br>';
            endwhile;
         }
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $output;

}
```

Comment: looks like my last respond was lost. Thank you Adam! That's it!